# How do I speedup encoding of a video that has just 1 static frame with ffmpeg and lib264 library?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

I'm making mp4 (libx264 + aac) videos that have just one static image throughout the whole video. It's basically a narrated text with a nice background.

The question I've is how could I speed up encoding of such videos? Currently the videos are encoding at 50fps which is very, very slow. I can only encode 2000 videos on a single computer in one day.

Any particular settings I could specify to ffmpeg or lib264 library to suggest that there is no motion, and it's just a single image that has to b

For comparison, I was doing .avi (divx + mp3) videos before I moved to mp4, and I was able to encode 6000 - 8000 videos per day.

Comment: First, ideally this question should have the command and the ffmpeg output; second, divx is a much simpler codec than h264, all other things being equal you will inevitably get longer encode times with h264 (but smaller and/or better-quality output files).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.m4a -loop 1 -r 2 -i image.jpg -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -shortest out.mp4
```

`-r 2` sets the frame rate to 2 fps (some players seem to have problems with 1 fps).